# Angular How to show http error message on login page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

on my login page ngMessage is used to show error message when form validation fails. But now need this div to be displayed when http 500 error occurs. I can get the corresponding error message when http error occurs, but just don't know how to display the ngMessage div at that time.

html:

```
<div class="error_msg" ng-if="form_login.$submitted" ng-messages="form_login.$error" flex="initial">
    <div class="alertmsg" ng-message="required" flex">{{errormsg | i18next}}</div>
</div>
```

controller:

```
loginModule.controller("loginController", ['$http', '$window', '$rootScope', '$scope', '$location', 'authenticationService', '$i18next', function($http, $window, $rootScope, $scope, $location, authenticationService, $i18next){

    $scope.newclass = false;
    $scope.errormsg = 'login.alertmsg';
    $scope.login = function(){
        if($scope.form_login.$invalid){
            return false;
        }else{
            $scope.newclass = true;
            $scope.dataloading = true;
            authenticationService.login($scope.username, $scope.password, 
                function(response){
                if(response.data.status_code == 200){
                    $window.location.href = 'view/home.html';
                }else if(response.data.status_code == 500){
                    $scope.errormsg = 'error_code' + '.' +response.data.payload.error_code;
                    console.log($scope.errormsg);
                    $scope.dataloading = false;
                    $scope.newclass = false;
                }
            },
                function(response){
                    $scope.dataloading = false;
                    $scope.newclass = false;

            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

update:
if I only use ng-if, both form validation message and http error message can be displayed, but without ngMessage, form validation message will not be dynamic

Comment: What you need to do is use your authentication service as an asynchronous validator. Asynchronous validation was added to AngularJS 1.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to deal with non-200 HTTP for all your XHR, not only for authentication. 
You can do this by using a http response interceptor that can evaluate the HTTP code of every angular XHR.

You will probably need to use messages in other features than login success or login error. You can create a controller for those messages, like login success, fail, user modifications success, fail... You can do this by listening for events in your message controller.

Then you can trigger events from your HTTP response interceptor to notify the message controller to show a message depending on the HTTP code.

Finnaly, if you want to deal in a different way with HTTP error code for your authentification, you can use a factorize $http with his own http response interceptor sending the message you want to the message controller.